# Calling curl from python script

Tags: python, api, powershell, curl

I am trying to use `curl` to connect to the Splunk API and run a search and store the results into a `.csv` file. I am able to make this work with the `subprocess` module and `powershell.exe`, shown in the code block below

```
powershell_path = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
search_string = '<search to be used>'
curl_command = '\ncurl -k -u <other args>'
subprocess.call([powershell_path, search_string, curl_command])
```

However, I would like to be able to do this without using the `powershell.exe`. I tried just substituting the path to the `powershell.exe` with the path to the `curl.exe`, but then I get errors telling me I have illegal characters in my `search_string` and `curl_command` variables (escaping them with a `\` doesn't help), and when I try to directly use the paths in the `subprocess.call`:

`subprocess.call(['<path to curl.exe>', '<full search string>, 'curl -k -u <other args>'])`

I get the error `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified` (I checked path to file and tried `os.join`, got nowhere). How can I use curl in Python to connect to the Splunk API, run a search, save the results to a `csv`, and do all this without calling external applications like Powershell?

Comment: Why do you want to use `curl` from Python? It has its own libraries for accessing URLs (I'd recommend `requests`, if you can install third party packages). If you just want to run command line tools, it would be easier to just write a shell script or batch file.

Comment: The tool that I was given to connect to the API is a `.ps1` file that uses `curl`. I just wanted to take the pieces in the script and use them from within the python script.